# "Index Out Of Range" error in UICollectionView when dataSource array is correct

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm using `sizeForItemAt indexPath` with a UICollectionView.

When I commit an action to remove an item from the collectionView and from the dataSource array, I call `reloadData`. However, in `sizeForItem`, I'm getting a `Fatal error: Index out of range`.

The dataSource count is correct, and is reflecting the change. For example, from 4 to 3 items. The indexPath that `sizeForItem` is trying to access is `0 - 3`, the fourth index.

Why am I getting this error? Does it matter that `sizeForItem` runs before either `cellForItem` or `numberOfItemsInSection`?

After removing the item and calling `reloadData`, `sizeForItem` is called. Here are the delegate and dataSource methods:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.updateStyle
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let view = array[indexPath.row]
    return view.intrinsicContentSize
}
```

Please let me know if I can clarify.

**Edit: Here's where I'm removing the item from the dataSource array**

```
func deleteItem() {
    removeItem(item)
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Show the part where you do the delete and reload.

Comment: @ozzieozumo Added

Comment: And where are you calling the deleteItems method on your collection view? Basically, I suspect that after your delete, your datasource has fewer items than your collection view.  You have to keep them in synch.

Comment: @ozzieozumo I'm calling `deleteItems` in response to a button press. Doesn't `reloadData` keep them in sync? I'm mutating the dataSource array and then calling `reloadData`

Comment: What is `item`? What does `removeItem(item)` do? Is this in your view controller or in you cell?

Comment: You are correct about reloadData, but the call to sizeForItem seems to be  happening before you call reloadData.  In your question, you  said "does it matter that sizeForItem runs before etc".  It matters if your collection and datasource are out of synch at the point that sizeForItem runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ozzieozumo said, the call to `sizeForItemAt indexPath` was getting called before `reloadData`.

After mutating the dataSource array, I changed the `reloadData` call to come first.